# How to Map a D3D11On12 render target to memory?

Tags: direct3d12, direct3d11on12

I am trying to map a offscreen D2D render target to memory.

- The render target is created as a `ID3D12Resource` with `D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_RENDER_TARGET`
- Then passed through `ID3D11On12Device::CreateWrappedResource()`
- Then made into a `ID2D1Bitmap1` with `ID2D1DeviceContext2::CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface`

The app draws on it with D2D, then it is used as a pixel shader resource in a D3D12 shader and I can verify that the content of the texture is correct this way.

However, if I copy it to a `D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_READBACK` resource through `CopyTextureRegion`, it comes back as fully set to 0. The code I use works for other textures. I tried after the `D3D11DeviceContext` is flushed, and also after the Present to screen is done.

I also tried to copy and map it in the D2D realm, but I have the same result. I feel this resource is special in some way and I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue. The problem was that I was outputting to a bitmap without alpha support, in combination with bad BlendDesc parameters. I confirm that D3D11On12 offscreen render targets work the same as any other resources when it comes to copying to a readback resource.